# JAVAFX CheckBox thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, checkbox, nullpointerexception

I have a list of Japanese dishes and the user select which dish will commande. I'm trying to check which ones of the `Checkbox`es are selected from a **thread** and print the price in a `Label` but when I run my code it returns `NullPointerException`

**here is my code:**

```
int price=0;

@FXML private Label textPrice;

//Dishes
@FXML private CheckBox salade;
@FXML private CheckBox soupeMiso;
@FXML private CheckBox soupe_miso_EBI;

 public void threadPrice() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    //selectedSushi() ;

                    if(salade.isSelected()) {
                        System.out.println("salade selected");
                        price=price+Sushi.SALADE.getPrice();
                    }

                    if(soupeMiso.isSelected()) {
                        price=price+Sushi.SOUPE_MISOU.getPrice();
                    }

                    if(soupe_miso_EBI.isSelected()) {
                        price=price+Sushi.SOUPE_MISOU_EBI.getPrice();
                    }


                }
            });

    }}).start();


    String strPrice = Integer.toString(price); 
    textPrice.setText("price:"+strPrice);
}
```

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>                                                          
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171"                                                     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"     fx:controller="application.MenuController">
  <children>
     <AnchorPane prefHeight="486.0" prefWidth="617.0">
       <children>
          <HBox layoutX="195.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="193.0">
           <children>
              <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MENU" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="195.6796875">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="52.0" />
                 </font>*
              </Text>
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox layoutX="25.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="578.0">
           <children>
              <CheckBox fx:id="soupeMiso" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Soupe Miso">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </CheckBox>
              <CheckBox fx:id="salade1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Salade">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </CheckBox>
              <CheckBox fx:id="soupe_miso_EBI" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Supe Miso EBI">
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                 </padding>
              </CheckBox>
           </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox layoutX="25.0" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="578.0" />
        <Label fx:id="textPrice" layoutX="204.0" layoutY="393.0" prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="196.0" text="price:">
           <font>
              <Font size="38.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Button fx:id="order" layoutX="215.0" layoutY="358.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectedSushi" text="ORDER" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

**Error:**

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"   
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.MenuController$1$1.run(MenuController.java:143)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How is the `threadPrice` invoked? How is the object you call this for created, how do you load the fxml and how does the fxml look (The parts with the `CheckBox`es and possibly the `Node` using `threadPrice` as event handler seem to of interest here.) Furthermore what are you trying to achieve using a `Thread` here? It's most likely that the `CheckBox`es do not change between calling the `threadPrice` method and the execution of the runnable used with `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: You get the `NullPointerException` at this line `String strPrice = Integer.toString(price);` ?

Comment: the issue is in salade.isSelected that returns null, i change the code and create a methode without thread like that: @FXML
 private void selectedSushi(ActionEvent event) {
  System.out.println("Check box");

  if(salade.isSelected()) {
   System.out.println("salade selected");
   price=price+Sushi.SALADE.getPrice();
  }

  if(soupeMiso.isSelected()) {
   price=price+Sushi.SOUPE_MISOU.getPrice();
  }

  if(soupe_miso_EBI.isSelected()) {
   price=price+Sushi.SOUPE_MISOU_EBI.getPrice();
  }
  String prix= Integer.toString(price); 
  textPrice.setText("Prix:"+prix);}

Comment: and it doesnt work, isSelected always returs null

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `isSelected`'s return type is primitive and therefore cannot be `null`. If something is `null`, it's `salade`, `soupeMiso` and/or `soupe_miso_EBI` are `null`. It's likely to be `salade` since the `fx:id` used in the fxml is `salade1`, but I've often seen a method being called for the wrong controller instance which would result in none of the nodes being injected.